# QComboBox keeps storing duplicate entries

Tags: qt, mingw, duplicates, qcombobox

`QComboBox` keeps storing duplicate strings entered by the user, even if I call its member function `QComboBox::setDuplicatesEnabled(false)`.

How can I store single copies of the strings even when the user inserts duplicates?

From [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#duplicatesEnabled-prop):

> `duplicatesEnabled : bool`
>   This property holds whether the user can enter duplicate items into the combobox.
>   Note that it is always possible to programmatically insert duplicate items into the combobox.
>   By default, this property is false (duplicates are not allowed).
>   Access functions:
>   `bool duplicatesEnabled () const`
>   `void setDuplicatesEnabled ( bool enable )`

Answer (score 7):

As the documentation says:

> This property holds whether the user can enter duplicate items into
>   the combobox. Note that it is always possible to programmatically
>   insert duplicate items into the combobox.

So this option doesn't affect string you set programmatically. You need to remove duplicates from your list manually.

For example, if you're storing your list in `QStringList`, duplicates can be easily removed using `list = list.toSet().toList()`.

Comment: I clarified my question. The end user is adding strings to the combo box.

Answer (score 1):

you need to check, if the userinput is valid (not duplicated or not) and catch the `void    editTextChanged ( const QString & text )` signal.

you could also derive your own class from `QComboBox` and overload the `void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event) // may be not the correct name`